# Sticky element inside a div with absolute position on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with `position: absolute` and `overflow: auto`. Inside this `div` I have a `div` that should act sticky and should be fixed(`top: 0, bottom: 0, overflow: auto`) when I scroll.

I can fix this `div`, but I can't return it to original position because I can't attached the scroll event when this `div` is fixed.

```
$('.right').scroll(function() {
    if ($('.scroll').offset().top <= 0) {
        $('.scroll').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': 0,
            'left': '20px',
            'right': '0',
            'overflow': 'auto'
        })
    }
})
```

Please check my JSFiddle for more info - [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a924dcge/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I would do it. This doesn't position it fixed but it has the same appearance. Once scrollTop is equal to or greater than where the top of the fixed content "should be" then we set the top absolutely to that of scrollTop, if you scroll upwards once the scrollTop reaches the point where the fixed content used to be, it will drop it again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  oldOffset = $('.scroll').offset().top;
  $('.right').scroll(function() {
    if ($('.right').scrollTop() > oldOffset) {
      $('.scroll').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': $('.right').scrollTop(),
        'left': '20px',
        'right': '0',
        'overflow': 'auto'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/a924dcge/8/))

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. But if `.right` has a scrolling it jumps and it break everything.

Comment: I mean `.scroll` with absolute position changes `.right`'s height.

Comment: Ah, I see. I can scroll down and the `.right` will be bigger and bigger

Answer (score 1):

Set the outside div to

```
position: relative;
```

Set the inside div to

```
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
right: 15px;
```

This will put the top right corner of the inside div at the designated location within the parent container.  When setting position absolute, the image is set relative to the first parent container with position defined to anything other than default, I believe.  If there is no DOM element assigned a position, the absolute element will be positioned relative to the viewport.

Comment: I can't set the outside div to `position: relative`.

Comment: It doesnt have to be relative it can be anything, but it has to be defined as something.  Relative works well because it positions the element relative to where it would normally lay, but if you just set it to relative and don't tell it to move, you can just use it for situations like this where you want to leverage this position: absolute trick.  Do you follow? It's a little tricky I admit.

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange task you want to accomplish :)

But anyway there is the problem:

When you set you inner `div` to `position: fixed` you positioned this `div` above your `div.right` and it is prevents scrolling event from fire.

So what you need is to set `pointer-events: none` to the `div.scroll` to allow your `div.right` listen scroll events without any problems.

But when you do that you will face another problem - when you set your `div.scroll` to `position: fixed` it will lose its place inside the `div.right` and `div.right` jumps to the top of the scroll automatically. To prevent that you need to create clone of the `div.scroll` and set his `height` to `0` initially, and to `auto` when your inner element is fixed.

**Note** `pointer-events: none` - disable all mouse events including the text selection.

There is the code:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cnt = $('.right');
    var scrollEl = $('.scroll');
    var scrollClone = scrollEl.clone().addClass('clone');
    scrollEl.before(scrollClone);
    cnt.scroll(function() {
        var expression = scrollClone.offset().top <= 0;
        scrollEl.toggleClass('stick', expression);
        scrollClone.toggleClass('stick-clone', expression);
    })
})
```

**CSS**

```
.scroll {
    background: yellow;
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden; /* Remove top offset from h1*/
}
.scroll.stick {
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.scroll.clone {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scroll.clone.stick-clone {
    height: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a924dcge/23/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following example:

Firstly, instead of adding the css as inline styles, create a css class that you can add and remove from the `.scroll` element.

CSS

```
.fixed-top {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:20px;
    right:20px;
}
```

Wrap your .scroll element with another div which will be used in the javascript to keep track of the original height of your `.scroll` div.

HTML

```
<div class="scroll-wrapper">
    <div class="scroll"></div>
</div>
```

Lastly, store the scrollTop value in a variable when the fixed position is applied for the first time. You can then use that value to determine when to remove the fixed styles from the `.scroll` div. Also set the height of the `.scroll-wrapper` element equal to the height of your `.scroll` element to make sure the content is scrollable.

Javascript

```
 var startScrollTop = 0;
    $('.right').scroll(function () {
        var $scroll = $('.scroll');
        if ($scroll.offset().top <= 0 && $('.right').scrollTop() > startScrollTop) {
            if (startScrollTop === 0) {
                startScrollTop = $('.right').scrollTop();
            }
             $('.scroll-wrapper').css("height", $('.scroll').height() + 300);
            $scroll.addClass("fixed-top");
        } else {
            $scroll.removeClass("fixed-top");
        }
    })
```

Take a look at this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/a924dcge/25/

Hope that helps!